# Assertion failure in +[JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I work on a Chat application using `JSQMessageViewController` third party framework (same as WhatsApp type). I am displaying list of chat members in a TableView. When I click one chat item needs to navigate chat view controller. This is my requirement.

Now, when I click one chat member in list view i get the following exception from class `JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.m`:

> “Assertion failure in +[JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory
>   jsq_circularImage:withDiameter:highlightedColor:],
>   /Users/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Factories/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.m:148”
>   and  “Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: image != nil'”

I am using the code of this project: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController
I am using this framework through cocoa pods.

Comment: You will have to provide source code, otherwise we cannot tell you where the problem is. Also, read the exception: `reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: image != nil'` it's probably telling you what your problem is.

Comment: actually i am not changes in my code. just i download the above framework and integrate in my project.

Comment: @Risadinha i got exception from this class : JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.m and in this class i got an exception from this method+ (UIImage *)jsq_circularImage:(UIImage *)image withDiameter:(NSUInteger)diameter highlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor{  NSParameterAssert(image != nil); }.. in this method i got an exception from this line of code :  NSParameterAssert(image != nil);

Comment: The parameter is obviously `nil` (not set) at this point in the code. Make sure you provide it, or check before for `nil` and do not call this code. Maybe you are calling it in the wrong order? (I have not checked the code you linked.)

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to include the avatar images in your project (under Images.xcassets), as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had a issue. Make sure your images that are being referenced and in your images folder.

Here's a part of my code I had to updated:

```
  blankAvatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithImage(UIImage(named: "blank_user"), diameter: 30)
```

and

```
 func cleanup() {
    userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "blank_user")
    nameField.text = nil;
}
```

I had to update the uimages referenced ^^

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think above techie people helps you in many different format. But if you don't want the sender's image in chat view controller, then just go to the "JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.m" and search for the method

```
+ (UIImage *)jsq_circularImage:(UIImage *)image withDiameter:(NSUInteger)diameter highlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor

// NSParameterAssert(image != nil);
```

and comment above line. Hope this help.